# Search with only list results

Tags: list-search-box

I have implemented a search bar in my SharePoint page, but currently, it is searching the entire site. However, I would like for it to give search results from a list of items (or two).

I have tried to use the list filter, but that doesn't work with wildcard searches. I am wondering if anyone can give me some insight how to set up the search settings (cause there are a

Comment: Which SharePoint version you are using? its a search page with search result webpart and need to setup query to return List items only?

Comment: I says it is version: 16.0.0.6816

Comment: you want to setup query in search result webpart?

Comment: Yes if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Search result webpart on the page, Edit webpart and click on Change Query.

Paste query

> (contentclass:STS_List OR contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary)

Which will return only list items and document library items.

If only list items require then

> contentclass:STS_List

See the image below. Hope this will help!

[image]